# "unknown node" error in Keras convolutional neural network

Tags: image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I have the following (2D) convolutional neural network in Keras for image classification with binary labels:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

To train it, I have a lot of (.jpeg) image files, but too many to load all at once. Hence I use the following generator (and preprocessing):

```
def load_preprocess(path):
    img = img_to_array(load_img(path, target_size=(128, 128)))
    output = rgb_to_grayscale(img)
    output = tf.reshape(output, (-1,128, 128, 1))
    return output

def image_generator(paths, labels, batch_size=32):
    while True:
        for i in range(0, len(paths), batch_size):
            images = [load_preprocess(path) for path in paths[i:i+batch_size]]
            target = labels[i:i+batch_size]

            yield(images, target)
```

I tried training the network using

```
model.fit_generator(image_generator(train_paths, train_labels), steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil(len(train_paths)/32)), epochs=1)
```

Here train_paths is a list of paths and train_labels is a binary numpy array with two columns.

However, this gives me the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Requested tensor connection from unknown node: "conv2d_input:0".
```

What causes this error and how do I solve it? I tried googling it, but I found no hits at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error: the images are tensors and should be converted to arrays. I do this as follows:

```
def image_generator(paths, labels, batch_size=32):
    sess = tf.Session()
    while True:
        for i in range(0, len(paths), batch_size):
            with sess.as_default():
                images = [load_preprocess(path).eval() for path in paths[i:i+batch_size]]
            target = labels[i:i+batch_size]

            yield(np.array(images), target)
```